# Things one should know/do to create a spectrogram

Tags: c++, windows, fstream, spectrogram

I am trying to create a spectogram hopefully from scratch using C++, that looks, more or less like this

[image]

it will take in audio from a mic, and just display the data, no need to write/read to binary files.

Now, I am lost as to what I need to know overall to create this program.

Currently, I am learning C++ fast, like all day non-stop. But, I get the feeling, it won't be done all in C++.

I am not asking for codes, just any advice how this could be achievable.
using C++, in Window7

Comment: Seems like Fast Fourier Transforms might prove useful here.

Comment: It will eventually end up being platform specific, you'll end up interfacing with the operating system in order to read from the microphone.  That aside, most of the math is signal processing, which will port very well between platforms.

Comment: You need to know 1) a good graphing tool or library, 2) a language such as C++ (at least the basics, this seems pretty straightforward), and 3) as much mathematics as is necessary to transform the audio data the way you want.

Comment: @Beta thanks. You saved me. for 1, if you mean graphical tool like photoshop, then I have tons of expertise in that are.2, I am learning the basics in C++, so I will do fine, 3rd not so much. Is that all? btw: are you available for freelancing?

Comment: I'm available, but this is a difficult project to pursue remotely, and I don't want to accept a job if I'm not sure I can finish it. Let's see how much we can rough out (gratis). Do you have an email address where I can reach you?

Comment: Yes. feel free to drop me a message anytime... hopefully soon. `webzuru@yahoo.com`